# Returning from __len__() when >64 bits

Tags: python, ipv6, long-integer

In this problem, I'm dealing with IPv6 network address spaces, so the length is `2^(128-subnet)`.

It appears that python (at least on this machine), will cope with up to a 64 bit signed number as the return value from `__len__()`. So `len(IP('2001::/66'))` works, but `len(IP('2001::/65'))` fails.

```
from IPy import IP
len(IP('2001::/64'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
      len(IP('2001::/64'))
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
```

The IPy library in question is at https://github.com/haypo/python-ipy.

Any suggestions on how to handle this, or hint that it might be a limitation I'm stuck with?

Comment: +1 because I'm interested in this. On x64 Win7, using Python 2.6, `len(IP('2001::/64'))` gives me `TypeError: __len__() should return an int` whereas `IP('2001::/64').__len__()` gives me `18446744073709551616L`. What does `IP('2001::/64').__len__()` give you?

Comment: @azhrei OverflowError instead of a TypeError in 2.7.3, but the same pattern with `.__len__()` working fine and `len()` raising the exception.

Comment: Well, comments in IPy's source code suggest it's a python limitation you're stuck with. http://bugs.python.org/issue3729 seems to report the basic issue, and that it was found in 2.6 and 3.0. The bug is closed as fixed, but I can't see where it was fixed. Might be worth trying Python 3.3 ?

Comment: @azhrei Python 3.2.3 gives me `OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer`. This might end up just being a documentation note to use `x.len()` and not `len(x)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue you're hitting is that Python's C API has a system-dependent limit on the lengths of containers. That is, the C function `PyObject_Size` returns a `Py_ssize_t` value, which is a signed version of the standard C `size_t` type. It's size is system dependent, but probably 32-bits on 32-bit systems and 64-bits on 64-bit systems.

The builtin `len` function uses `PyObject_Size`, so it has the same limitations. Here's [its current implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e87364449954/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1312):

```
static PyObject *
builtin_len(PyObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;

    res = PyObject_Size(v);
    if (res < 0 && PyErr_Occurred())
        return NULL;
    return PyInt_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

You can work around this limitation by using the `len` method on the `IP` object, rather than calling the builtin `len`:

```
IP('2001::/64').len()
```

This is pure python, so it doesn't have any limitations on integer size.

Comment: Cool. I'll put it into IPy's documentation.

Comment: Would it be worth reporting this as a bug? There is no reason why lengths and indices can't go over that size, especially when we have "virtual" sets like this one.

Comment: @LambdaFairy I'm confused. Reporting it to who as a bug?

Comment: Reporting it to the Python developers. According to the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), `__len__` should return "an integer". A very large integer is still an integer.